Android Espresso Integration Test How To Run Code Before onCreate method of Activity?
How do i run code before onCreate called in my test activity?
@Before is called after onCreate which causes problems.
Im using
public ActivityScenarioRule<MyActivity> activityScenarioRule = new ActivityScenarioRule<>(MyActivity.class);

To launch the activity.

One way to prepare app state before activity creation is to remove the ActivityScenarioRule usage and call ActivityScenario yourself.
// execute after your preparations are done
scenario = ActivityScenario.launch(MyActivity.class)

// execute after test is done
scenario.close()

